# Meaning of “Videre Sed Non Videri”

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, meaning, sentence-translation, infinitive

What is the meaning of “Videre Sed Non Videri”?

I already search on Google on pages like:

[mymemory.translated](https://mymemory.translated.net/en/Latin/English/videre-sed-non-videri)

But results are confusing me, and my knowledge on Latin language is zero.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is a military saying and [here it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9zkv.jpg) on my work mug

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Salve!, and welcome to the site!

The translation you point is missing a word or two, but it's not too far from correct. A fairly literal translation is:

> *To see but not [to] be seen*

- **Videre** and **videri** are, respectively, the active and passive infinitives of the verb for seein, hence: *to see* and *to be seen*.
- **Sed** is an adversative conjunction, *but*.
- **Non** is an adverb of negation. In this case, it negates the following verb, just as English *not* would do

---

**Update:** One could also make a case for an alternative translation:

> *To see but not to seem*,

if the context allows it to make sense. **Videri** can also mean [*to seem, appear to be*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dvideo), as brilliantly explained by Sebastian Koppehel in [this answer](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dvideo)

Answer (score 2):

It’s a military saying: "see but not be seen." It is used by recce and sniper teams and any other covert observation platoons.